# How to get rid of annoying security message in terminal during upgrade?

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade

Every time I use a command: `sudo apt upgrade` in terminal I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# You can verify the status of security fixes using the `pro fix` command.
# E.g., a recent Ruby vulnerability can be checked with: `pro fix USN-6219-1`
# For more detail see: https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6219-1
#
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Help me please to get rid of this message "You can verify ..."

And where did it come from? I can not understand why I see it now?

Comment: I believe this is what Canonical calls "APT News". See below link on how to disable this.

Comment: @artur-meinild thank you! That's what I was looking for.
`sudo pro config set apt_news=false` - worked for me.